# Rational numbers in an array c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to enter fractions to an array and don't know which data type should i make this array with to get back the numbers when needed as fractions in c++

```
Float numbers [5]={7/6,1/6,5/66,1/42,1/30,4389/698} ; cout << numbers[3] ;
```

The output will be 0 and it should be 0.238 so what should I do to make it 0.238 ?

Comment: use `std::cout << std::setprecision(2) << numbers[3];`

Comment: You need to write a representation of fractions and use that instead of floating point numbers. (The `float` closest to 1.6 is 1.60000002384185791015625, which is 13421773/8388608.)

Comment: Sorry, i wrote it wrong could you please look at the last edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please share your environemnt? OS/Compile type/version?
In my environment,

```
float numbers [6]={5.5,4.7,2.8,1.6,9.3,8.2} ; std::cout << numbers[3] << std::endl;
```

the output is 1.6. and it should be 1.6.

BTW, there are 6 items in this array, so the size should be 6 but not 5.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote it wrong could you please look at the last edit

Comment: This is because the operator(/) is a little confused, if both the 2 numbers around `/` are integer, the result will be integer, if one of the numbers is float, the result will be float, so actually, numbers are equal to 1 0 0 0 0 6 0.

Comment: If you want to get the float result, should cast one of the number into float. like `float numbers[6] = {7.0/6,1.0/6,5.0/66,1.0/42,1.0/30,4389.0/698};`, then the result will be `1.16667 0.166667 0.0757576 0.0238095 0.0333333 6.28797 0.0238095`, and so numbers[3] is 0.0238095.

Answer (score 2):

int / int   ==> int

```
 float a = 1 / 42;
 cout << a << endl;//0
```

float / int ==> float

```
float A = static_cast<float>(1) / 42; // OR A = 1.0/42;
cout << A << endl;// 0.238
```

You can :

```
 float numbers[6] = { 7.0 / 6 , 1.0 / 6, 5.0 / 66 ,1.0 / 42, 1.0 / 30,4389.0 / 698 }; 
 cout << numbers[3];
```

Comment: Sorry, I wrote it wrong could you please look at the last edit

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code works perfectly fine if you want the output to be 1.6:

```
float numbers[]= {5.5,4.7,2.8,1.6,9.3,8.2} ; 
cout << numbers[3] ;
```

Comment: Sorry, I wrote it wrong could you please look at the last edit